# библиотека для отображения математических формул

Tags: android, android-studio

Долго пытаюсь найти хорошую библиотеку, в которой хотя бы у view объекта можно поменять цвет текста и выровнять формулу по центру. Везде какие-то наложения и так далее.
Я пробовал:
1) https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView - не меняется цвет текста 
2) https://github.com/gregcockroft/AndroidMath - не выравнивается текст, но меняет цвет
3) https://github.com/kostub/iosMath - текст как-то накладывается друг на друга.

Comment: Вам надо весь текст окрасить или выделять некоторые символы?

Comment: ну вот есть TextView и с ним приятно работать, когда же я подключаю библиотеки по работе с математическими формулами, то всё криво. 
Мне нужно выделить весь текст белым цветом

Comment: Проф-библиотека для отображения формул - MathJax . Хотите менять цвет: всего лишь используйте css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая ваша библиотека - обертка над MathML. Она генерит WebView, в котором и отображается формула. Можете изменить цвет текста, добавив атрибут mathcolor тегу math. [В примере, лежащем с библиотекой на гитхабе](https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/kexanie/mathviewtest/MainActivity.java), он даже используется

```
 String mathml =
            "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\" display=\"block\" mathcolor=\"black\">\n" +
            "  <mrow>\n" +
            "    <mi>f</mi>\n" +....
```